How can I differentiate between Kendo UI (server) versus Kendo UI (client)?
I am using ASP.Net Core 6.  I am forced to use Kendo UI to build tables (Grid).  There are 2 "flavors" of Kendo UI:
What I call "Server":
@(Html.Kendo().Grid<Model>().Name("grid").Columns(columns =>
{ columns.Bound(c => c.TypeOfVisit).Width(140); ...

And: "Client"
<script src="js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
$("#grid").kendoGrid({...

Why do these 2 technologies share the same name?  It is infuriating to try to find guidance on the web as the results crisscross between these 2 technologies.
Can anyone tell me the secret handshake to search for each of these separately?  How can I specify that I am looking for "Server" examples vs "Client" examples?
BTW - Shame on you Telerik!

They share the same name because the end result is effectively the same - html and javascript to display Kendo UI controls on the page in the browser.
Your "Server" example is Razor syntax using the server side 'MVC wrapper' classes. That runs on the server when the page is being constructed and emits the html and javascript for the grid to render once the browser receives it. The server then delivers the resulting page to the browser.
Your "Client" example is jQuery syntax whereby the grid is instead constructed by client code after the page has been received.
Hence you can build Kendo UI controls on either the server or the client or both.
The best place to start when looking for examples is https://demos.telerik.com/kendo-ui/grid/index
The landing page for each control shows the example using jQuery but there are links to show the equivalent for Angular, React, Vue, ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core.
Obviously jQuery, Angular, React and Vue are client side with ASP.NET MVC and ASP.NET Core being server side. Tailor your searches accordingly depending on what you are working with.

That's just it.  What do I tailor the searches to..?  If I search for "Kendo UI Grid jQuery", I get a mixed bag of results.  Kendo should be specific on naming each "version" of the Kendo UI Grid jQuery to specify server approach or client approach.  This is very frustrating when trying to get up to speed with the technology.
